# The Last Supper - Vanishing Points

Tags: linear-perspective

The vanishing point seems to be at the center of the frame, where the parallel lines seem to meet.

I am wondering why the parallel lines of the semi arch are pointing down.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Please excuse my ignorance. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The arch is not a painted part of the painting**, but a physical part of the room in the [Santa Maria delle Grazie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Maria_delle_Grazie,_Milan) above which the mural can be found:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://e-arthistory5.blogspot.com/2018/03/leonardos-last-supper.html)</sup>

Comment: The actual fact is that a door was cut right through the painting, so the part referred to was simply removed from the painting. See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Supper_(Leonardo)) for details.

Comment: Why is it relevant that the arch is not painted? What would be different if it was painted?

Comment: @TanZor As virolino pointed out, the door was cut through the fresco around 150 years later, when it was in such a deteriorated state it was almost indiscernible. It was never part of the painting surface or the depicted scene. The OP thought it was part of the scene, because we know it from photographs where the frame is always present.

Comment: Yes but why does this matter for the question of vanishing points?

Comment: @TanZor It doesn't, it's completely unrelated, but the OP didn't know this.